# Как организовать без помощи плагинов поиск ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Как в Wordpress сделать без помощи плагинов поиск Ajax?

Comment: При обострении плагинофобии достаточно взять код плагина и запихать его в тему :)

Comment: @SeVlad, ага... а в конце приписать: Где в этом коде могут быть потенциальные проблемы безопасности? Сразу набегут хакеры, и будут критиковать.

Answer (score 2):

Да как любой другой ajax - делаете input, по нажатию клавиши отправляете ajax-запрос с текстом, в php-части вызываете `get_search_query($search_string)`, возвращаете результат в js. Все просто.

Comment: Можете пример самого sql запроса скинуть ?

Comment: Нет никакого sql-запроса. В WordPress есть функции почти на все случаи жизни. Для поиска - вот та, что я привел в ответе. Используйте ее.

Comment: просто опыта в вп мало очень, может какой то пример у вас найдется?

Comment: Нет, писать код за автора вопроса тут не принято. Читайте отличный материал по данному вопросу https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html пишите свой код, а потом возвращайтесь со своим кодом, если что-то не получится.